# Can a Function Mapping into a Higher Order Domain be Continuous?

Tags: continuity

Just a simple question: Can a function mapping $\mathbb{R}^m$ into $\mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuous function when m < n?

My gut says "No." My brain says "Go to bed already."

I'm trying to prove something using a result that holds for continuous functions $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, but it seems like that won't be an appropriate assertion if I have to worry about continuous functions that map $\mathbb{R}$ to a higher dimension.

Comment: So the map $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ which takes $t$ to $(t,0)$ should not be continuous?

Comment: I think you want your map to genueinly higher dimensional range but you did not mention that. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve for such functions.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang well...I guess it is time for bed if I can't see that haha. Thank you.